# Haskell SDL app on macOS doesn't recognize keyboard/mouse when run with runhaskell

Tags: macos, haskell, sdl

I'm running into a weird problem when running sdl-apps under macOS. Compiled apps run fine, but when i try to run the same code with runhaskell (or more specifically stack runghc) a window opens with no title bar and doesn't react to mouse or keyboard input. Doing the same under Windows or Linux works fine though.

Is there anything like a command line argument or something that i can do about that or do i just have to live with this?

SDL system librarys were installed via homebrew and the haskell libs via stack lts-8.3

Comment: Can you give a reference to the source code of an app you aim to run with `runhaskell`?

Comment: literally any SDL-app I've tried, e.g. https://github.com/haskell-game/sdl2/blob/master/examples/lazyfoo/Lesson01.hs